# Area of maximum rectangle

Tags: geometry

Two circle of radii 3 and 6 touches inside . What is the area of the maximum rectangle outside the circle of radius and inside the circle of radius 6 ?

Comment: you have some thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG let the circles be $x^2+y^2=36$ and $(x-3)^2+y^2=9$.  From the geometry (draw it!) it will be clear that the largest rectangle would be of form $(-x, y), (0, y), (0, -y), (-x, -y)$, i.e. with a side on the diameter of the larger circle / $Y$-axis.

This rectangle has dimensions $x$ and $2y$, so the area you maximise is $2xy$, subject to the constraint $x^2+y^2=36$.  But $2xy \le x^2+y^2 = 36$, so the maximum area is 36.

Answer (score 1):

Is calculus allowed? If yes, the question looks simple... Taking coordinates in polar form  eases the simplification.